# View multiple instances at once

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, pyhook

In turtle graphic I have a sheet of multiple instances of one class with the same name.
I would like to display these instances differently on the screen, but I don't know how.
I always only get one and not all of them.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle("square")
turtle.color("red")
list_turtle = [turtle,turtle,turtle,turtle,turtle,]
list_turtle[0].forward(20)
x = list_turtle[0].xcor() 
y = list_turtle[0].ycor()
list_turtle[1].goto(x+60,y+20)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have multiple instances with the same name.

A list does not multiply its objects. It stores adress that references those objects (a so called pointer). (graphical explanation and more here: https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:640/format:webp/1*vHFX7V3Wx-ckpa3RmDfRmw.png)

Think of it like copying your friends phonenumber 10 times into a list. Then you call each phone number and issue an order. You do not suddenly have ten friends, but one friend who executes all your commands.

You need to instantiate each turtle seperately using
`a_new_turtle = Turtle()`

You can use a function to do that for you ( see my solution). I made the turtles different colors to separate them better on the screen.

```py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
def make_turtle(form: str = "square", color='red'):
    turtle = Turtle(form) # this line makes a new instance of class "Turtle", a new turtle is generated here
    turtle.color(color)
    return turtle

# turtle instances are now made in the list
list_turtle = [make_turtle(color='blue'), make_turtle(color='green'), make_turtle(), make_turtle(), make_turtle(), ]
list_turtle[0].forward(20)
x = list_turtle[0].xcor()
y = list_turtle[0].ycor()
list_turtle[1].goto(x + 60, y + 20)
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Answer helped me understand what I was doing wrong.